# Не работает фильтрация массива

Tags: javascript

Возникла проблема с фильтрацией массива для страницы интернет-магазина. Фильтрация происходит по принципу выбора chechbox и нажатия кнопки "Применить". Задача проверить на выбранные параметры товара (empty, lounger, scratching, gameComplex, house).
Сам массив:

```
    let catalogItems = [
  {
    id: 0,
    src: 'url(../img/catalog/catalog-img-1.jpg)',
    srcset: '',
    title: 'Эконом',
    size: false,
    area: '0.63',
    price: 100,
    empty: true,
    lounger: false,
    scratching: false,
    gameComplex: false,
    house: false,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    src: 'url(../img/catalog/catalog-img-2.jpg)',
    srcset: '',
    title: 'Эконом плюс',
    size: '90х100х180',
    area: '0.90',
    price: 200,
    empty: false,
    lounger: true,
    scratching: true,
    gameComplex: false,
    house: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    src: 'url(../img/catalog/catalog-img-3.jpg)',
    srcset: '',
    title: 'Комфорт',
    size: '100х125х180',
    area: '1.13',
    price: 250,
    empty: false,
    lounger: true,
    scratching: true,
    gameComplex: true,
    house: false,
  }
];
```

Данные о выбранных товарах вытягиваются с помощью FormData и передаются в нужные переменные. Данные получаются корректно, но массив возвращается пустой. Код фильтрации:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
  var Data = new FormData(form);
  equipments = Data.getAll("equipment[]")
  ev.preventDefault();
  filterCatalog();
}, false);


var filterCatalog = function () {
  var catalogArray = catalogItems
  if (equipments.length >= 1) {
    catalogArray = catalogArray.filter(e => {
      equipments.forEach(element => {
        if (e[element] === false) {
          return false
        } 
      })
     
    })
  }

  renderCatalog(catalogArray)
}
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: у тебя callback передаваемый в filter ничего не возвращает, а должен возвращать true или false

Comment: Не могли бы подсказать, где я должен его возвращать? А то уже голову сломал при исправлении данной ошибки

Comment: вынеси этот коллбэк отдельно и посмотри что он у тебя возвращает

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Вынес в отдельную переменную и все получилось

Comment: `catalogArray.filter(product => equipments.every(equipment => product[equipment]))`

Answer (score -1):

```
// catalogItems где-то объявлена выше
    
    const neededQquipments = ['lounger', 'scratching'];
    
    const filterCatalog = (items, equipments) => items.filter(item => equipments.map(equip => item[equip]).indexOf(false) === -1);
    
    const filteredItems = filterCatalog(catalogItems, neededQquipments);
    
    console.log(filteredItems);
```